# iterm2 imgcat not working at remote

Tags: iterm2

I'm using iterm2 on a mac and ssh-ing into a remote RedHat host. When I try viewing an image in the terminal using imgcat, I just get a placeholder icon.

[image]

I have no idea why it's failing. Any suggestions? imgcat works fine on my mac, but when I ssh to a remote host it gives this unexplained failure.

Comment: It's possible there's no termcap file on the remote server that recognizes iTerm's $TERM entry. Try `TERM=xterm-256color ~/.iterm2/imgcat temp.jpg` If that works then you should be able to set your TERM type in iTerm's preferences to the same xterm-256color and it should work from now on.

Comment: Didn't work :( $TERM is already set to ''xterm-256color". Any other ideas? Is there a way I can check if there's a termcap file on the RHEL server? I'm not at all familiar with these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 5):

I havent figured out the problem with the imgcat script that was installed by running iTerm2's `Install Shell Integration` script. However, I did find a work around through the python pypi package also called `imgcat`; so if you're having trouble with iTerm2's imgcat on a remote server (or otherwise), you might want to try the following:

```
pip install --user imgcat
$HOME/.local/bin/imgcat your-image.jpg
```

This python version also provides better options than iTerm2's, namely, you can specify --height H, --width W without having to edit the script itself.